# Identical asp.net web pages, except for 1 column. Currently 2 different aspx forms - can one set properties before redirecting?

Tags: asp.net, properties

I have 2 pages, which are identical, except for one column in a database (with sensitive information), which should not show in one of the pages.

E.g.

```
myPageIncludeSensitiveInfo.aspx
myPageExlucdeSensitiveInfo.aspx
```

At this point, each page is in a seperate code-behind file, and I need help on finding out how to do this in one page please. There is a `pagebaseclass` which is used for security.
I am not allowed to use `Querystrings`,

```
e.g. myPage.aspx?include=true 
or   myPage.aspx?exclude=true
```

In windows pages I would have had the option:

```
dim myPage1 as new myPage
myPage.bIncludeSensitiveInfo = False
myPage1.show()
```

but with `asp.net forms` it is a `response.redirect` and I don't know if one could set properties beforehand.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use querystring-parameter(reasonable in this case), use the `Session`.

```
Session("includeSensitiveInfo") = True
Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx")
```

and on `myPage.aspx` (assuming columns means a column in a `GridView` and it's the first):

```
gridView1.Columns(0).Visible = Session("includeSensitiveInfo") IsNot Nothing _
            AndAlso DirectCast(Session("includeSensitiveInfo"), Boolean)
```

[Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)